# извлечь из массива и присвоить в переменные JavaScript

Tags: javascript, массивы, регулярные-выражения

Дана строка:

```
str = ' +1-921-512-2222 <Wilfrid Stevens> Wild Street AA-67209'
```

необходимо извлечь данные в такие переменные: name, phone, address. Порядок следования данных в строке смешанный, но всегда имя - в угловых скобках, номер - это группы цифр с разделителем "-", иногда первый символ в такой подстроке начинается с '+' и оставшиеся подстроки - это адрес.
Преобразуя `str.split(' ')` получаю `[' ', '+1-921-512-2222', '<Wilfrid', 'Stevens>', 'Wild', 'Street', 'AA-67209']`.
Пытаюсь вытянуть через регулярные выражения нужные подстроки:

```
let [
    name = temp.search(/[<>]/g),
    phone = temp.search(/[+-]/g),
    ...address
  ] = temp
```

но, требуемого результата не получаю.
Нужно ли преобразовывать строку в массив и как в этом случае быть с подстрокой, содержащей имя

```
<John Smith>
```

эта подстрока разбивается на два элемента...
Корректны ли регулярные выражения для извлечения требуемых значений?
Какой наиболее оптимальный алгоритм решения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не факт, что канонический вариант в плане регулярок - просто удовлетворяет озвученные условия.

```js
str = ' +1-921-512-2222 <Wilfrid Stevens> Wild Street AA-67209';

let nameArr = str.match(/<(\D+)>/);
let phone = str.match(/\+?\d+[\-,\d]+/)[0];
let address = str.replace(nameArr[0], '').replace(phone,'').trim();
let name = nameArr[1];

console.log([name, phone, address]);
```

Comment: //expected
//'Phone => 1-908-512-2222, Name => Peter O\'Brien, Address => High Street  CC-47209'
//to equal
//'Phone => 1-908-512-2222, Name => Peter O\'Brien, Address => High Street CC-47209'

почти идеально, в переменную address присваивается подстрока с лишним пробелом в самом начале...
Похоже в комментарии этот пробел игнорируется...

Comment: Порядок же может быть разным, если адрес вначале, то и пробела не будет. Можно `trim()` убрать, выкинуть последний пробел, если есть. Это только основа, продуманная реализация на вас. Если '+' в телефоне не нужен, то тоже сгруппировать после него все остальное можно как в name. Поработайте, попробуйте довести до нормальной рабочей версии.

Comment: Спасибо за отклик, отложу задачку на попозже

Comment: А в принципе, требуемые данные (name, phone, address) проще вытянуть из массива или из строки? Или без разницы?

Comment: Конечно лучше из организованных данных, из объекта с ключами и соответствующими значениями. Этот объект можно преобразовать в строку JSON, а из нее восстановить объект.

Comment: в контексте этой темы: приходит строка с множеством данных, разделенных '\n', одна из подстрок строки типа: ' +1-921-512-2222 <Wilfrid Stevens> Wild Street AA-67209' причем порядок следования данных(телефон имя адрес) в подстроке не строгий; я мыслил так что преобразуя сплитом эту подстроку я получу массив типа ['+1-921-512-2222', '<Wilfrid Stevens>', 'Wild', 'Street', 'AA-67209']. Через спрэд / через деструктуризацию попробую вытянуть [name, phone и оставшиеся элементы массива в ...address].

Comment: Так порядок же нестрогий, в спрэд может попасть и телефон и имя, по идее))